# Aggregate of DateTime split in Date and Time columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query

```
from booking in query
join ba in Context.BookingAddresses on booking.Id equals ba.BookingId into collections
let firstCollection = (from d in collections where d.AddressType == BookingAddressType.Collection select d.RequestedDate).Min()                            
where
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(queryArgs.DateFrom.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(firstCollection) &&
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(queryArgs.DateTo.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(firstCollection)
select booking;
```

In the let clause I would actually need the Min of a merged DateOnly and TimeSpan value
d.RequestedDate [DateOnly] + d.RequestedDateTimeFrom [TimeSpan] that look like this in the DB:

```
RequestedDate : 2013-06-01
RequestedDateTimeFrom : 13:50
```

This does not compile:

```
let firstCollection = (from d in collections where d.AddressType == BookingAddressType.Collection select d.RequestedDate + d.RequestedDateTimeFrom)
```

Edit: In the meantime I thought of a different approach, that would actually solve my main issue, namely, that if there are more datetimes that have both the date and time values the same, I compare them by a thrid Sequence column. So it boils down to simple sorting as this:

```
from booking in query
join ba in Context.BookingAddresses on booking.Id equals ba.BookingId into collections
let firstCollection = collections.OrderBy(c => c.RequestedDate).ThenBy(c => c.RequestedFromTime).ThenBy(c => c.Sequence).FirstOrDefault()
//(from d in collections where d.AddressType == BookingAddressType.Collection select d.RequestedDate).Min()
where
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(queryArgs.DateFrom.Value) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(firstCollection.RequestedDate) &&
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(queryArgs.DateTo.Value) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(firstCollection.RequestedDate)
select booking;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the most elegant way (and untested, to be honest), but I would try an imbricated [SqlFunctions.DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466214.aspx)  with [SqlFunctions.DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466330.aspx) on the TimeSpan

```
SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", 
                      SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", d.RequestedDateTimeFrom), 
                      SqlFunctions.DateAdd("mi", 
                                            SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", d.RequestedDateTimeFrom), 
                                            d.RequestedDate);
```

(You may also use `EntityFunctions.AddHours` and `EntityFunctions.AddMinutes` instead of `SqlFunctions.DateAdd`)

Comment: Edited : `mi` for minutes, not `mm` (which are months)

Comment: Yeah, seems like a last resort solution if nothing works :) But I just edited my original post how I solved it with a different approach. It's really simple, don't know how it didn't occur to me earlier...
But I'd be still interested if there was a better solution to "merging" these values..?